# how to access deleted browser history using chrome on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, history

I accidentally deleted my chrome browsing history. Is there anyway I can recover it?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate (2009)

Comment: do you have a backup?

Comment: no i don't have a backup unfortunately